# Accessing keys in a list of dicts

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x

I have the following json api response:

```
 ['{"results":[{"keyword":"value1","found":"false","matches":"","correction":""}, 
 {"keyword":"value2","found":"true","matches":"company","correction":""}]}']
```

The type of data is "<class 'list'>"
I am trying to print the same list only excluding sections with found:false.

Desired output:

```
 ['{"results":[{"keyword":"value1","found":"false","matches":"","correction":""}]}']
```

I tried all kinds of methods, working with different data types in python can be frustrating.

Comment: Loop over each item. Parse it to a json object or object so that you can read the found value - print accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is like commenter Asad Awadia pointed out to do the following:

1. parse the JSON info to a more useable object
2. Split or filter it in a way so you can easily get to the found:
3. Filter depending on that input
4. If needed, put it all back together, but without the unneeded info